# Ionic - meta charset doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, cordova, special-characters, ionic-framework, htmlspecialchars

In my index, I've inserted this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
<meta charset="UTF-8">
```

And if I use a special character (like `à` or `•`) in the index it's displayed correctly. For example, in the header I can use special character.

But if I use it in one of the view, it's display a exclamation point in a rhombus. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it myself.
I changed the file encodings in IntelliJ (setting -> editor -> file encodings).